# I want to connect my android app with my website's database

Tags: php, android, json, android-activity

I am creating android app of my website.I want to know which changes are necessary to make in my php files in order to connect my android app to my website's database as these files have no echo statement or I have to make another php files for these purpose.Please help as I am new to android.My first file is login.php

```html
<?php require_once('Connection/cnn.php'); ?>
<?php 
session_start();
if((isset($_POST['admin_login'])) && ($_POST['admin_login']=="form99"))
{
$_SESSION['username']=$_POST['txt_email'];
$_SESSION['password']=$_POST['txt_password'];
header('Location: login-pass.php');
}
if($_SESSION['verified']=='Y')
{
 header('Location: transporter-account.php');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Transporteazy</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<!-- MAIN BODY WRAPPER START -->
<div id="main-Body-Wrapper">

<!-- HEADER PART START -->
<div id="header-con">
 <?php include ('header.php'); ?>
</div>
<!-- HEADER PART END -->





<!-- MIDDLE PART START -->
<div class="how-it-work">
 <div class="left-part">
    <?php if($_GET['msg']=='error') {?>
<h1>Please login below to see posted loads or <a href="transporter-registration.php" target="_self">click here</a> to register with us.</h1>
<?php } else {?>
<h1>Login Area</h1>
<?php } ?>
        <div class="login">
            <?php $page=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; 
  if ($page!="") {  ?>
  <div class="error">
  <?php if ($_GET['error']=="empty") { ?>
  <p class="alert">Please enter user name & password.</p>
  <?php } else if ($_GET['error']=="name") {?>
  <p class="alert">Please enter user name.</p>
  <?php } else if ($_GET['error']=="pass") {?>
  <p class="alert">Please enter password.</p>
  <?php } else if ($_GET['error']=="nouser") {?>
  <p class="alert">Something is wrong.</p>
  <?php } else if ($_GET['error']=="pend") {?>
        <p class="alert">You are not a authorize person to access further pages.</p>
        <?php }?>
  </div>
  <?php }?>
                <h3>If you are already registered, please login here.</h3>
                <div class="loginBox">
                 <form name="login-form" id="login-form" method="post">
                    <table width="420" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="150" align="right" valign="middle">Email Address :</td>
                        <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="txt_email" type="email" class="input" id="txt_email" value="" required placeholder="abc@xyz.com"/></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="middle">Password:</td>
                        <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="txt_password" type="password" class="input" id="txt_password" value="" required placeholder="*********"/></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="Submit" type="submit" class="loginBtn" value="" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="admin_login" value="form99"/></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="left" valign="top"><a href="forgot-password.php" target="_self">Forgot Password?</a>  <font color="#FF0000">|</font> <a href="transporter-registration.php" target="_self">Register here</a></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    
    <!-- RIGHT PART -->
     <div class="right-part">
         
             <?php include('benefits.php');?>
            
        </div>
    <!-- RIGHT PART -->
    
    
</div>
<!-- MIDDLE PART END -->




<!-- FOOTER PART STRAT -->
 <div class="footerCon">
     <?php include ('footer.php'); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- FOOTER PART END -->


</div>
<!-- MAIN BODY WRAPPER END -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well if you do a google search youll find alot of usefull steps and information about that

Comment: Try this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: make sure you only provide READ ONLY access to the neccesary fields for the user. Never allow an app to write. It's too easy to hack if you keep your details in your app. One would only need to take your dbconnect class from your app, import it in java, access the database and voila, they can do whatever they want. Best way I would think is just use a quick json interpreter communication setup. That way you fully control what is done by what.